Maui Button Cannot Left Align and Expand Button?
I have just added my first Content Page in MAUI, and I want a button that will be clickable.
The button will not expand to the frame unless I centre the text, which I don't want to do.
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="StimpCalculator.Views.AboutStimp"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:StimpCalculator.ViewModels"
         Title="About XX Calcuator">

<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <viewModels:AboutStimpViewModel />
</ContentPage.BindingContext>
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Padding="20" Spacing="20">
        
        <StackLayout Spacing="5" HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                   FontSize="Large"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Version}"
                   FontSize="Medium"
                   TextColor="Gray"
                   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <Frame HasShadow="False"
               BorderColor="Gray"
               Padding="10">

            <Button 
                Text="Get This Working" 
                HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
            />

        </Frame>

    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
</ContentPage>



First of all, the xxxAndExpand attribute has been deprecated in MAUI, you can check the official document about the LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand Field.
But I tested your code on both xamarin and maui, the result were same.

The button will not expand to the frame unless I centre the text, which I don't want to do

Centering the text it the button't default behavior. If I change the StartAndExpand to Fill:
<Button 
       Text="Get This Working" 
       HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>

I got this:

And if you want the button fill the Frame and keep the button's text at the start. You need to call the platform code.
Give the button a name:
<Button x:Name="button"
       Text="Get This Working" 
       HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>

And call the platform code in the code behind:
        protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
        {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
            var btn = button.Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.Maui.Platform.MauiButton;
            btn.HorizontalContentAlignment = Microsoft.UI.Xaml.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
#elif ANDROID
            var btn = button.Handler.PlatformView as Google.Android.Material.Button.MaterialButton;
            btn.TextAlignment = Android.Views.TextAlignment.ViewStart;
#elif IOS
            var btn = button.Handler.PlatformView as UIKit.UIButton;
            btn.TitleLabel.TextAlignment = UIKit.UITextAlignment.Left;
#endif
        }

And I got this:

Finally, the Frame was deprecated in MAUI, you can use the Border instead.
